# How to ignore quoutes when retrieving data from mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, select, quotes

I am trying to compare two tables in mysql, everything works fine, till my python script wants to retrieve "name"time"

the error message is something similiar to:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \ald"time" AND something = "Donald"time" UNION SELECT  id  FROM table1 WHERE something' at line 1')
```

My mysql sentence looks like:

```
SELECT  id FROM table1 WHERE something =  "Donald"time"
```

I know that I could ignore the " with many tricks but unfortunately I do not know the quotes position to simply insert an Escape Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Like this with the `\` escape:

```
create table a
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    b varchar(100) not null
);

insert a(b) values ('aabbcc'),('fish\"tonite');

SELECT  id FROM a WHERE b =  "fish\"tonite";
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
```

Mysql Manual page [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) containing info on some escape sequences.

Comment: Thank you @Drew, the solution works when you know the position of the quotes, but when you dont how could this work?

Comment: I am afraid you lost me. Parse it and find it? I am just showing how to insert, and how to know it is there. You need to parse and wedge in the escape sequence. Get that into a string. And use that in your where clause

Comment: So let's say you have a string: `AFAFEIVUDFA`. Let's say any one of those place holders actually can be a double quote symbol. You need to parse it, and wedge a `\` before every one of those double quotes (expland it). Now you have a second string. You use that in your where clause